# Wepack force typescript files to be included using ts-loader

Tags: typescript, webpack, ts-loader

I've gotten into TypeScript and played around with Browserify (with tsify), it worked fine until I switched to Webpack to use vue and babel with my project.

Here is my project structure (simplified, it's also using ASP.NET Core) :

```
BestAppEver
  ---| [C# stuff]
  ---| scripts
       ---| pages
               - Login.ts
               - Dashboard.ts
       ---| components
               - CoolThing.vue
       - App.ts
  - package.json
  - webpack.config.js
  - tsconfig.json
```

The files in `pages` usually contain jquery declarations like these:

```
import * as $ from "jquery";
console.log("hi i got loaded!");
$("#deleteConfirmationInput").change(function() {
    if (isInputValid()) {
        $("#deleteConfirmationButton").removeAttr("disabled");
    } else {
        $("#deleteConfirmationButton").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
});
```

And this is my `webpack.config.js` file

```js
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin');
const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require('tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
    entry: './scripts/App.ts',
    mode: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'wwwroot/js'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader',
            },
            {
                test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'ts-loader',
                        options: {
                            appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.vue', '.json'],
        alias: {
            'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
        },
        plugins: [
            new TsconfigPathsPlugin()
        ]
    }
    plugins: [
        new VueLoaderPlugin()
    ],
    devtool: 'source-map'
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
    module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                NODE_ENV: '"production"'
            }
        }),
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            minimize: true
        })
    ]);
}
```

With Browserify and tsify, all the files were included and ran, so `"hi i got loaded!"` was printed out.

With ts-loader, **only the files that i `import`ed and used are included and ran.** Without importing the file, `"hi i got loaded!"` was not printed out. This wasn't the case with `.vue` files.

Is there a way to automatically import those files and make them all run in the final bundle?

Thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is exactly what you discovered: you must import the files! Webpack only traverses the file tree starting from the file you name as the `entry` (`./scripts/App.ts`). Anything else is simply never seen by webpack.

Note that you can use "bare imports" to import the file only for the side effect:

```
import "./pages/Login.ts";
```

In this case, you are telling webpack that you don't expect `Login.ts` to export anything, but the file should be included in the bundle. You can place these bare imports in your `App.ts`.

This question may be relevant: [ES6 Bare Import: How to use, and when?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32773912/es6-bare-import-how-to-use-and-when)

---

Another option is configuring webpack to use multiple values for [`entry`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context). In your case, you should be able to define `entry` as an array of strings:

```
entry: [
  './scripts/App.ts',
  './scripts/Pages/Login.ts',
  './scripts/Pages/Component.ts'
],
```

If you want to be clever, you can dynamically generate this by recursively listing files in the `scripts` directory. `webpack.config.js` is just javascript (node) after all. If interested, I can expand the answer to include an example of this.